# Adding text to div changes width of its neighbours

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a following HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column1"></div>
    <div class="column2"></div>
    <div class="column3"></div>
</div>
```

Class `.row` is a flexbox set to be a row. Classes `column1` and `column2` have set fixed width property in CSS. However class `column3` doesn't have that property. When I'm adding text to that container, it changes width of the rest two containers.

I tried properties `white-space: no-wrap`, `overflow: hidden`, `overflow-wrap: break-word`.

None of these properties prevent changing width of other two columns. How can I fix it so all three columns will have fixed width but `column3` will adjust automatically when window size is changed?

Answer (score 2):

If you add `flex-shrink: 0` to the `column1` and `column2` flex items, this will prevent their getting smaller. (`flex-grow: 0` would do the same for getting larger, but that's already the default setting for this property, so you don't need to add it.)

Comment: Thanks for advice! It helped! However there's still one more problem I wasn't aware about previously. Now when all columns to the left of column3 have fixed width and don't shrink, column3's width grows to available 100% spare size which is size of the entire window. I tried to use calc(100% - fixed_columns_width) with no effect. How to create a rule so 100% width for that column 3 means 100% width of parent, not body?

Comment: thanks this helped, also you can use `width: -webkit-fill-available;` on the element that is super long